# Did Spyder ever add a "Find all references" shortcut for Spyder 5?

Tags: ide, keyboard-shortcuts, spyder, shortcut

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4184

Is this really STILL not available? IF so, probably have to switch to pycharm or go with Eclipse as this is mad.

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) If issues are open on Github, it means they haven't been implemented yet, sorry.

We're a small development team (four people) and there have been more pressing things to solve/implement during the last years.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for making this clear. I do however think this is a critical shortcut which should exist in any IDE. Hopefully it will come out soon. Thanks.